# Callback function in dojo.io.script.get

Tags: json, dojo, jsonp

I am trying to get some JSON from an external url. This works fine with the twitter request in the example in the dojo documentation.

I guess the problem comes with the callback function, as I'm not sure if I need one and where to place it.

The JSON looks like:

```
{"upcoming":[]}
```

and that's how I call it:

```
     function getJSON(){
   // Look up the node we'll stick the text under.
   var targetNode = dojo.byId("results");

   // The parameters to pass to xhrGet, the url, how to handle it, and the callbacks.
   var jsonpArgs = {
     url: url,
     load: function(data){
         console.log(data);
       // Set the data from the search into the viewbox in nicely formatted JSON
       targetNode.innerHTML = "<pre>" + dojo.toJson(data, true) + "</pre>";
     },
     error: function(error){
       targetNode.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
     }
   };
   test = dojo.io.script.get(jsonpArgs);
 }
 dojo.ready(getJSON);
```

ant that's the output I get:

```
JSON:
{
    "returnValue": true,
    "timeStamp": 1332858447300,
    "eventPhase": 0,
    "target": null,
    "defaultPrevented": false,
    "srcElement": null,
    "type": "load",
    "cancelable": false,
    "currentTarget": null,
    "bubbles": false,
    "cancelBubble": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to this statement in your example?

```
// The parameters to pass to xhrGet, the url, how to handle it, and the callbacks.
```

If so, the "callbacks" are the load and error functions.

Comment: I refer to the callback function described at dojo.io.script

well, I think the problem was a missing callback function of the server concerning the json data. If I understood the thing correctly, I must receive a callback function from the server whick "includes" the JSON data, correct?

If that is correct, I have the solution of the problem :)